# Nginx config issue: getting 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, nginx, config

I'm trying to set up a web application using Nginx, but when trying to access it I am getting a 403 error. I've followed various different approaches to solving this including making sure that my permissions are set but to no avail.

here iss the config for the web application:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name         localhost

    index               index.php index.html index.htm;
    root                /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/webapp;
    port_in_redirect    off;

    # Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~* /\.ht {
        deny            all;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

    # Pass PHP scripts on to PHP-FPM
    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
 }
```

I ran `chmod -R 777 my-app` to give it all permissions.

yet I still get the 403 error.

Comment: What is the URL that you're trying to access?

Comment: 127.0.0.1, trying to access it on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `;` on your `server_name` directive, which would normally be a syntax error, but in your case it translates to:

```
server_name localhost index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

Which may be a weird list of server names, but more importantly, it means you do not have an `index` directive. This means that you will get an HTTP 403 response code whenever you attempt to list a directory such as `/`.

Comment: yes, this seemed to solve the 403, no I'm on to a 404! which I may start a new question about.